# Client not able to connect to Server using WinSock in C++

Tags: c++, winsock

I am making a simple client server application where the client sends an image file(.jpg) to the server. But, the client is not able to connect to the server. Please tell me where I am going wrong. This is what I have done.

Client:

```
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET m_socket;
    SOCKET m_backup;
    sockaddr_in con;
    SOCKET AcceptSocket;

    WComm::WComm()
    {

        // Initialize Winsock.
        int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
        if (iResult != NO_ERROR)
            printf("Error at WSAStartup()\n");

        // Create a socket.
        m_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

        if (m_socket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return;
        }

        m_backup = m_socket;


    }
    void WComm::connectServer(char *ip, int port)
    {
        // Connect to a server.
        con.sin_family = AF_INET;
        con.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
        con.sin_port = htons(port);

        if (connect(m_socket, (SOCKADDR*)&con, sizeof(con)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("Failed to connect.\n");
            WSACleanup();
            return;
        }
    }
    int WComm::sendData(char *sendbuf)
    {
        return send(m_socket, sendbuf, strlen(sendbuf), 0);
    }


    int WComm::recvData(char *recvbuf, int size)
    {
        int sz = recv(m_socket, recvbuf, size, 0);
        recvbuf[sz] = '\0';
        return sz;
    }


    void WComm::closeConnection()
    {
        closesocket(m_socket);
        m_socket = m_backup;
    }
    void WComm::fileSend(char *fpath)
    {

        // Extract only filename from given path.
        char filename[50];
        int i = strlen(fpath);
        for (; i>0; i--)if (fpath[i - 1] == '\\')break;
        for (int j = 0; i <= (int)strlen(fpath); i++)filename[j++] = fpath[i];
        ////////////////////////////////////////

        ifstream myFile(fpath, ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);
        int size = (int)myFile.tellg();
        myFile.close();

        char filesize[10]; itoa(size, filesize, 10);


        send(m_socket, filename, strlen(filename), 0);
        char rec[32] = ""; recv(m_socket, rec, 32, 0);

        send(m_socket, filesize, strlen(filesize), 0);
        recv(m_socket, rec, 32, 0);


        FILE *fr = fopen("C:\\Images\\abc.jpg", "rb");

        while (size > 0)
        {
            char buffer[1030];

            if (size >= 1024)
            {
                fread(buffer, 1024, 1, fr);
                send(m_socket, buffer, 1024, 0);
                recv(m_socket, rec, 32, 0);

            }
            else
            {
                fread(buffer, size, 1, fr);
                buffer[size] = '\0';
                send(m_socket, buffer, size, 0);
                recv(m_socket, rec, 32, 0);
            }


            size -= 1024;

        }

        fclose(fr);

    }

WComm w;


    void main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {

    runclient(argv[1], argv[2]);
}
    void runclient(char *ip, char *fpath)
    {
        char rec[32] = "";

        // Connect To Server
        w.connectServer(ip, 27015);
        printf("Connected to server...\n");

        // Sending File
        w.sendData("FileSend"); 
        w.recvData(rec, 32);
        w.fileSend(fpath);
        printf("File Sent.............\n");

        // Send Close Connection Signal
        w.sendData("EndConnection"); w.recvData(rec, 32);
        printf("Connection ended......\n");
    }
```

Server:

```
#include "wcomm.h"

WSADATA wsaData;
SOCKET m_socket;
SOCKET m_backup;
sockaddr_in con;
SOCKET AcceptSocket;

WComm::WComm()
{

    // Initialize Winsock.
    int iResult = WSAStartup( MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData );
    if ( iResult != NO_ERROR )
        printf("Error at WSAStartup()\n");

    // Create a socket.
    m_socket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP );

    if ( m_socket == INVALID_SOCKET ) {
        printf( "Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError() );
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    m_backup = m_socket;


}
void WComm::startServer(int port)
{
    // Connect to a server.
    con.sin_family = AF_INET;
    con.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "0.0.0.0" );
    con.sin_port = htons( port );

    if ( bind( m_socket, (SOCKADDR*) &con, sizeof(con) ) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf( "Failed to connect.\n" );
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    // Listen on the socket.
    if ( listen( m_socket, 1 ) == SOCKET_ERROR )
        printf( "Error listening on socket.\n");

}

void WComm::waitForClient()
{
        AcceptSocket = SOCKET_ERROR;
        while ( AcceptSocket == SOCKET_ERROR ) {
            AcceptSocket = accept( m_backup, NULL, NULL );
        }
        m_socket = AcceptSocket;
}

int WComm::sendData(char *sendbuf)
{
    return send( m_socket, sendbuf, strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
}


int WComm::recvData(char *recvbuf,int size)
{
    int sz = recv( m_socket, recvbuf, size, 0 );
    recvbuf[sz] = '\0';
    return sz;
}


void WComm::closeConnection()
{
    closesocket(m_socket);
    m_socket = m_backup;
}


void WComm::fileReceive(char *filename)
{

    char rec[50] = "";


    recv( m_socket, filename, 32, 0 );
    send( m_socket, "OK", strlen("OK"), 0 );

    FILE *fw = fopen(filename, "wb");

    int recs = recv( m_socket, rec, 32, 0 );
    send( m_socket, "OK", strlen("OK"), 0 );

    rec[recs]='\0';
    int size = atoi(rec);


    while(size > 0)
    {
        char buffer[1030];

        if(size>=1024)
        {
            recv( m_socket, buffer, 1024, 0 );
            send( m_socket, "OK", strlen("OK"), 0 );
            fwrite(buffer, 1024, 1, fw);

        }
        else
        {
            recv( m_socket, buffer, size, 0 );
            send( m_socket, "OK", strlen("OK"), 0 );
            buffer[size]='\0';
            fwrite(buffer, size, 1, fw);
        }


        size -= 1024;

    }

    fclose(fw);

}

WComm w;

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
runserver();
}
void runserver()
{
    // Start Server Daemon
    w.startServer(27015);
    printf("Server Started........\n");

    while (TRUE) {

        // Wait until a client connects
        w.waitForClient();
        printf("Client Connected......\n");

        // Work with client
        while (TRUE)
        {
            char rec[50] = "";
            w.recvData(rec, 32); 
            w.sendData("OK");

            if (strcmp(rec, "FileSend") == 0)
            {
                char fname[32] = "";
                w.fileReceive(fname);
                printf("File Received.........\n");
            }


            if (strcmp(rec, "EndConnection") == 0)break;
            printf("Connection Ended......\n");

        }

        // Disconnect client
        w.closeConnection();
    }

}
```

Also, if I want to send more than 1 image, then what should I do for that? Would going for Generic List be a good idea to hold all the images which I want to send? How to go for this? Please help

Comment: How the receiver side should know where ends the filename and starts the filesize? And where ends the filesize and starts the  file itself? How about instead of raw socket using something more high level like HTTP protocol where such problems were solved already?

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky how to do this using HTTP protocol?

Comment: [WSAGetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741580(v=vs.85).aspx), use it.

Comment: @n.m. where and how to use WSAGetLastError

Comment: Read the linked article. Use [google](http://google.com) to fill the gaps.